# Mercedes Benz W203 C-Class C220 CDI whining noise

Tags: noise, automatic-transmission, mercedes-benz, differential

I have my W203 (Automatic Transmission 722.6) that is killing me with this whining noise when i let the release the gas pedal and the sound change intensity depending on the speed. It starts when decelerating just under 100km/h, it increase until the 50 / 55 km/h and then it goes down again. It stops when i go under 20km/h. [image: Noise Chart]

There are no error codes and someone say it can be the GearBox but it costs a lot to repair, someone else say it can be the differential.

Comment: Do you know if it does it in reverse?

Comment: I didnt tried it in an elevated speed in reverse but with a common reverse it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is try and identify were the noise is coming from. This might work. Jack up the drive wheels,run the engine and with a long steel 1/4 rod with a wooden bung on the end touch each part of the engine, gear box,diff,wheel hubs,etc., with the bung on your ear. That would tell you if a bearing was suspect. This system is used to ident leaking water pipes in in the ground even today. It is great fun when you hit the right area. 6MM x 1m screwed rod can be got from diy outlets. Good luck.